# C# XmlReader ReadElementContentAsString() InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, xml, invalidoperationexception

I'm trying to read a particular XML, save the necessary information into two different classes `Order` and `OrderDetail`. However, when I try to read "BuyerID" from my XML with the following code, it throws me an `InvalidOperationException`, with The `ReadElementContentAsString method is not supported on node type None. Line 1, Position 634`: http://pastebin.com/Lu4mKtwq

At this particular line:

```
order.CustomerID = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
```

My source code: http://pastebin.com/JyTz8x0G

This is the XML that I am working with:

[image: Order xml that contains information for order and order detail class]
XML in text:

```
<Orders>
<Order ID="O2">
<OrderDate>1/7/2016</OrderDate>
<BuyerID>WSC1810</BuyerID>
<OrderItem>
<Item ID="R1">
<ItemName>8GB RAM King</ItemName>
<Decscription>8GB RAM King</Decscription>
<Capacity>8GB</Capacity>
<Quantities>150</Quantities>
<existingUnitPrice>100.00</existingUnitPrice>
</Item>
<Item ID="R2">
<ItemName>4GB RAM King</ItemName>
<Decscription>4GB RAM King Brand</Decscription>
<Capacity>4GB</Capacity>
<Quantities>100</Quantities>
<existingUnitPrice>50.00</existingUnitPrice>
</Item>
</OrderItem>
<RemarksandSpecialInstruction>Fragile, handle with care</RemarksandSpecialInstruction>
</Order>
</Orders>
```

The classes that I'm working with:
[image: Order and Order detail classes]

Comment: Can you post the XML Input also as a text , instead of an image ?

Comment: Also out of curiosity, if your intent is to convert XML into object and vice versa why not simply use serialization and deserialization instead of reading every property ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ReadElementContentAsString` method after reading the current node moves to the next one.
So in your case after having the below code

```
reader.ReadToFollowing("OrderDate");
order.OrderDate = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
```

Now the code is already at OrderID, so don't try to read it again.
Instead do something like the code below:

```
        while (reader.ReadToFollowing("Order"))
        {               
            order.OrderID = reader.GetAttribute("ID");
            string orderID = reader.Value;

            reader.ReadToFollowing("OrderDate");
            if(reader.Name.Equals("OrderDate"))
                order.OrderDate = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
            if (reader.Name.Equals("BuyerID"))
                order.CustomerID = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();               
            orderList.Add(order);
            while (reader.ReadToFollowing("Item"))
            {
                OrderDetail i = new OrderDetail();
                i.OrderID = orderID;                  
                i.ItemID = reader.GetAttribute("ID");

                reader.ReadToFollowing("Decscription");
                if (reader.Name.Equals("Decscription"))
                    i.Description = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                if (reader.Name.Equals("Capacity"))
                    i.Capacity = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                if (reader.Name.Equals("Quantities"))
                    i.Quantity = reader.ReadElementContentAsInt();
                if (reader.Name.Equals("existingUnitPrice"))
                    i.AskingPrice = reader.ReadElementContentAsDecimal();
                orderDetailList.Add(i);
            }
        }
```

Also make sure that your xml and your model are a match.

Answer (score 0):

The customer id is actually being read correctly,  it's the line below that which is raising an exception.
Your error is on this line of code:

```
reader.ReadToFollowing("Instructions");
```

The reason why is that the xml does not contain the element `Instructions`. 
You could improve your code by not discarding the result of `ReadToFollowing`

```
if (reader.ReadToFollowing("Instructions"))
    reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
```

Comment: I changed it to the correct element name, but it still points to the same place